# Sending email without phpmail() function

Tags: php, smtp, hosting, phpmailer

[see the image- first column -fields of phpmail and send email](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E3EQJ.png) -
My website is hosted on a web hosting site which does not support phpmail() function and smtp. Now i want to send emails from my website in order to verify the users with the verification code when he/she registers for an account on my website. 
I just want to know that is there any alternate method to send emails from my website that doesnt support phpmail and smtp feature? 
Thanks in advance
The question is not same as mentioned by bucketman as i dont want to use phpmailer() but an alternative..

now from that pic..plz tell me what does it mean? are phpmail and phpmailer  different or same?

Comment: yes@LeonardChallis

Comment: @bucketman..that question tells to use phpmailer..i am asking for alternative to phpmailer

Comment: there are plenty of services out there that can send the mail for you. You connect to them trough their API (http) so that should be an option. And most of them have a generous free tier. Just google for mail API

Comment: Can you please rewrite your question? There is no such thing as phpmail() function. How exactly do you know your hosting does not support it?

Comment: No, you can't send a form directly to email like that. You're not asking for an alternative to PHPMailer, you're asking for an alternative to PHP's `mail()` function or SMTP access, which all PHP email classes will need. The alternative is to use a service that has an HTTP API for sending email. Or use a hosting service that has a clue.

Comment: okk..i have added a pic..what does it suggest? see first column for phmail and end email fields